# why in this case, I can use for instead of switch-case

Tags: c#

I have a method, inside this method, at first, I use switch-case like this:

```
public int setDeviceName 
        {
            set
            {
                device_id = value;
                DeviceNoList[(page_no - 1) * display_data_num + selectedTagNo - 1] = value;
                switch (selectedDeviceNo)
                {
                    case 1:
                        lblLocation1.Text = lblDeviceName_Selected(device_id);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        lblLocation2.Text = lblDeviceName_Selected(device_id);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        lblLocation3.Text = lblDeviceName_Selected(device_id);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        lblLocation4.Text = lblDeviceName_Selected(device_id);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        lblLocation5.Text = lblDeviceName_Selected(device_id);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        lblLocation6.Text = lblDeviceName_Selected(device_id);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        lblLocation7.Text = lblDeviceName_Selected(device_id);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        lblLocation8.Text = lblDeviceName_Selected(device_id);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return device_id;
            }
        }
```

After, I tried to do For loop instead like below:

```
public int setDeviceName 
        {
            set
            {
                device_id = value;
                DeviceNoList[(page_no - 1) * display_data_num + selectedTagNo - 1] = value;
                Label [] lbl_Location = { lblLocation1, lblLocation2, lblLocation3, lblLocation4, lblLocation5, lblLocation6, lblLocation7, lblLocation8 };
               //set deviceName to each label in form
                for(int i = 0; i<display_data_num; i++)
                {
                    lbl_Location[i].Text = lblDeviceName_Selected(device_id);
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return device_id;
            }
        }
```

I have checked, my program still goes well, I don't know Can I use For instead of Switch-case like that or not. If not, why my program still work. I am new in programming.

Comment: That will only work if you have a `lbl_Location` variable which is a collection of some kind, containing the same values as variables `lblLocation1`, `lblLocation2` etc. In general, when you *do* have multiple values like this, a collection is easier to work with than lots of separate variables. As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to look into .NET naming conventions and start following them as early as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "your program still goes well". In the for loop version you didn't even mention `selectedDeviceNo`... Is that a redundant variable then?

Comment: @JonSkeet Looks like standard WinForms conventions to me, apart from the spacing

Comment: So you are assigning the same value to every label?

Comment: it goes well because you´ve coded it so it still works. How should anyone here know what exactly you´ve done whrong or right? You surely changed something in your code, because a for and a switch do completely different things. Without further work you can´t simply replace the one by the other.

Comment: @Charlieface: `device_id` certainly isn't, nor `display_data_num`. (Yes, the WinForms designer creates unconventional names by default - I'd argue it's best to override that and choose more meaningful and conventional names there as well...)

Comment: I edit my post with full of code block, so please look again and give me a help  @HimBromBeere

Comment: Your first code sets _one_ label. Your second code sets _all of them_. Well I _think_ it does - it depends on what `display_data_num` is exactly.

Comment: @mjwills it means my second set 1 value to all of label?

Comment: Yes. So the two sets of code are doing completely different things. So comparing them is like comparing running and swimming. They are both quite different.

Comment: BTW - `setDeviceName` is a terrible property name. `DeviceName` would be OK. Also, your property is doing **too much** - particularly if you are a new programmer.

Comment: well, obviously you put all your labels into an array within the setter of  `setDeviceName` (horrible name as mjwills already mentioned). Then you loop that array and assign a new text to every element. What exactly isn´t clear to you?

Comment: oh, I see, I got your point but I wonder if two methods are doing is different but it did not throw any error. I checked all of my function before and after I edit this code block, I get same result-change deviceName

Comment: Generally said for and switch are completely different things. You can´t exchange one by the other as a for-statement is a looping thing and a switch is a branch-decision thing. However you *may* create the **same** functionality by using **different** approaches.

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes, this is what I did. I wonder is that okay or not? Because I know for and switch-case is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for loop is better than switches and ifs when there are many different cases, all being a number in order. There are many reasons why but the best is: which is easier to read and write? 100 lines of cases or a few lines if a for loop?

In this scenario if you can change it to be in this form, it will be much better. We cannot move it straight over how you wanted, though, because indexing (`[i]`) doesn't work how you seem to think it does. Indexing grabs the value at the specified index of the collection, maybe an array, a list, etc..

If we change our `lbl_Location1`, ... to an array:

```
string[] lbl_Location = new string[]{ "a value 1", "a value 2", "and more" };
```

Obviously change the strings to the value and type of your choice. You can then do what you want and iterate through the indexes, which is better. Note that indexes start at `0`! The first value is `0`, second `1`, etc..

Implementation (notice I changed your condition in the for statement to the length of the array, this is a cleaner and simpler way to do it. Unless you were doing something different where that wasn't just the length of the array, just stop using that and use this):

```cs
for(int i = 0; i<lbl_Location.Length; i++)
                {
                    lbl_Location[i].Text = lblDeviceName_Selected(device_id);
                }
```

If you don't understand something or I misunderstood please comment!

#### More information on indexing:

So let's say I have a variable called `MyString1`. What you were trying to do with `MyString[1]` (I have replaced `i` with a 1 to further simplify this) is "look for a (for simplicity's sake) array called `MyString` and look at the second (remember, indexes start at zero!) position." What you wanted it to do was just add a `1` at the end. When we make it an array, we are essentially making one variable that is a container for many values.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I am not sure about it:" because indexing ([i]) doesn't work how you seem to think it does. Indexing grabs the value at the specified index of the collection, maybe an array, a list, etc.." Can you explain more, pls

Comment: wow, thank you, I know what I was wrong(maybe) through your comments. I think because of my display_data_num and lbl_Location.Length has same value (=8) then my program still working?

Comment: @HuyenThu you will still have to change your variables to an array for that solution. I have added more detail at the end about indexing. For further information I recommend researching *arrays in c#*

Comment: @HuyenThu I now see you are using WinForms from the comments. If you are using the designer in visual studio, it might be a bit tough to change that. Maybe use panels? Best of luck

Comment: thank you, it's really helpful to me because I am learning, even when I posted my question, I still, worry is that stupid question or not. But with comments, I have learned a lot

Comment: thank you so much, I will search for it-array in  c#